# share dict between process

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a `dict` that I want to share with 4 processes that modify values in that `dict` in real time. The dict is created with `Manager().dict()`
The question is, do I need to lock the resource every time a process modify the `dict`? What if 4 processes access to this `dict` in real time?

Comment: then you will have race conditions ... most likely ... it depends on how you are altering it (are they all altering the same keys? different keys(eg each process gets its own key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see undefined behavior then.  Here's a simple test program:

```
def worker(t):
    d, i = t
    d[i % 10] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp
    pool = mp.Pool()
    d = mp.Manager().dict()
    for i in range(10):
        d[i] = 0
    pool.map(worker, ((d, i) for i in xrange(1000)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print d, sum(d.values())
```

And here's sample output from 3 runs:

```
{0: 97, 1: 96, 2: 98, 3: 96, 4: 96, 5: 99, 6: 97, 7: 96, 8: 96, 9: 94} 965
{0: 97, 1: 97, 2: 96, 3: 97, 4: 97, 5: 97, 6: 95, 7: 95, 8: 93, 9: 96} 960
{0: 98, 1: 97, 2: 98, 3: 96, 4: 97, 5: 95, 6: 97, 7: 97, 8: 97, 9: 98} 970
```

To get the "expected" count of 100 in each bucket, you need to create a `mp.Manager().Lock()` object too, pass it, and use it in the `worker()` to protect the dict mutation.

Comment: Rather than do the locking in the worker explicitly, it might by nicer to subclass `multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy` and wrap `_callmethod()` in the lock/unlock, then register the new type to `SyncManager` as `syncDict` or something.  I'm actually kind of surprised there isn't a factory or something for making synchronized  managed objects already...

Comment: I agree, this means the users should care about lock every time they want to share state between process!

Comment: It's a tradeoff for sure, but multiprocessing works exactly the same way as multithreading in this respect - except that it's *far* more expensive to share state across processes than across threads.  The way it is, after adding all the locking code at least you'll *know* why your multiprocessed code runs slower than a 1-legged pig ;-)